windows powershell using tee to get output and file
I'm doing my project on VScode and using the Powershell as my terminal.
And i want my executable file shows on stantard output but also direct to a file.
At first,I only do like this
 .\mytest.exe .\myinputfile > myoutput.txt

This get only a file,but i can't trace the code.
And I search online and find that you can use tee to get what i want
so i change my cmd to this,
 .\mytest.exe .\myinputfile  | tee myoutput.txt

but this gets the file only.
what can i do to get also the stdoutput and the file?
do i misunderstading the object tee ?

Your use is correct: Tee-Object should take the Success Stream(aka stdOut), print it to the indicated file, and then pass it down through the pipeline which would, generally, mean being printed on-screen if nothing else is involved. Have you tried with another program(as it might be an issue with your program)? for example  ping.exe -n 1 google.com|Tee-Object .\test.txt. As alternative, try to pipe to Write-Output after Tee-Object

Does this answer your question: Can you redirect Tee-Object to standard out??

How does "mytest.exe" produce the output that you want to capture? If it directly writes to the console (e. g. using WriteConsole() instead of using WriteFile() with a standard output handle), then it can't be redirected using the > operator.

If mytest.exe writes to stderr, try: .\mytest.exe .\myinputfile *>&1 |Tee-Object -FilePath myoutput.txt

Solved.
I forget that the start of my output writes to stderr.
others message shows on stdout normally!
